# How to add "mailto" to a list of email addresses?

Tags: microsoft-excel

just wondering if someone might know how to add "mailto" to a list of email addresses I have in an excel spreadsheet?
Some of the email links aren't working and I really don't want to have to go through them one-by-one to add the "mailto" extension if possible..
Any help would be much appreciated.
John.S

Comment: Find and replace is your friend. Or a simple formula using CONCAT in another column.

Comment: Hi music2myear, 
thanks for your reply..
I need to add the "mailto" at the start of each email address, can you tell me how to do this using - find and replace?
Sorry for my ignorance!  Not an expert with excel by any measure..

Answer (score 1):

We can use HYPERLINK formula to add another column for the email address list. For example: We have a list of email address in Excel.

[image]

Add another column for Mail To, in cell B2, enter this formula **=HYPERLINK("mailto:"&A2)**, press **Enter**.

[image]

Drag the fill handle down to the cells in Mail To column. Then the email address column can be converted to mailto hyperlink.

[image]

Comment: You can also use Concatenate if you don't need/want them converted to actual links.